# Why would a Firebase Cloud Function be much slower once deployed than in the emulator, other than cold starts?

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions, dart2js

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that parses some HTML among other things. I've measured the HTML-parsing method itself, and it takes about 300ms in the emulator on a MacBook Pro. It seems to take about 4-8 seconds when deployed to Firebase, which is not a tolerable duration for my application.

I am using Dart to write my Firebase Cloud Functions using [firebase_functions_interop](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_functions_interop) and compiling to JS with Dart2JS. The method that is performing drastically differently between environments is actually Dart's built-in HTML parsing method. I know cold starts are a common reason for cloud functions taking longer than expected, but it seems like that's not the culprit here, since I'm explicitly measuring the time it takes to parse the HTML, and that's where I'm seeing the huge difference.

Is it to be expected that a Cloud Function would run drastically slower in production than on a MacBook Pro?

Comment: It would be good to see the code of your Cloud Function: correctly managing the CF life cycle can be key in terms of performance.

Comment: How many times have you tested it? If just once that might be due to cold start...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you deploy a firebase cloud function, you can customize the [runtime environment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation). But here, there isn't CPU capacity. If you have a look to [Cloud Function documentation directly](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#compute_time) (Firebase Cloud Functions are backed by Google Cloud Functions) you can see the correlation between the quatity of memory and the CPU power.

*Note: 4Gb of memory = 2CPU @2.4Ghz, not 1 CPU (one thread) @4.8Ghz*

So now, deploy your Firebase Cloud Function with 2Gb of memory, the speed should be better (by default it's 256Mb). But Keep in mind this: Cloud Function is mono CPU, and limited to 2.4Ghz. Your macbook pro should have 8 or 16 CPU, and with 3.4Ghz of processing power.

Comment: This made a tremendous difference. HTML documents that were being parsed in 4-8 seconds are now down to around 250ms. I had no idea you could (indirectly) configure the CPU capacity! Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that if you send the response to the request (e.g. **response.sendStatus(200)**) early in your cloud function and after that do some other tasks, then those other tasks are processed way slower (factor > 10) than if you wait with sending the response until after those tasks.